# Wildfly Database Module Authentication : How to record logins

Tags: jsf-2.2, wildfly-8

Hi I have implemented Wildfly Database Module Authentication for a JSF 2 application running on Wildfly 8. The authentication mechanism works perfectly, but I have a requirement where I need to create a record of the user's log ins. I  am supposed to calculate a login expiry date calculated as 2 weeks from the 1st login.

How can I invoke some custom code after successful authentication?

Or is it maybe possible for me to implement the functionality with an HttpSessionListener?

Comment: Thank you. So it looks like registering the Undertow Servlet Extension would be the best bet for me. I am going to attempt that. Failing that I should read up on the request.login() and try do authentication that way.

Comment: I attempted to create the UndertowHandlerExtension, register it in META-INF/services and bundle the jar into my application but ran into many issues locating the right dependencies. I am stuck though with a NoClassDefFoundError for org/wildfly/extension/undertow/security/JAASIdentityManagerImpl.I'm not sure what dependency to include for this..